# TooManyActualInvocations exception when creating @Nested tests in @WebMvcTest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockito, junit5, spring-test-mvc

I am trying to group my tests in a @WebMvcTest using @Nested, but unfortunately, a few of my tests stated failing with TooManyActualInvocations exception.

Here is minimal example I arrived at:

The test:

```
@WebMvcTest(value = AController.class)
public class AControllerMvcTest {
    @MockBean
    BService bService;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Nested
    class NestedTests1 {
        @Test
        void testOne() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Test One started");
            Mockito.when(bService.getDummyString()).thenReturn("dummyResp1");
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/underTest"))
                   .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
            Mockito.verify(bService).getDummyString();
            System.out.println("Test One finished");
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class NestedTests2 {
        @Test
        void testTwo() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Test Two started");
            System.out.println(bService.hashCode());
            Mockito.when(bService.getDummyString()).thenReturn("dummyResp2");
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/underTest"))
                   .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
            Mockito.verify(bService).getDummyString();
            System.out.println("Test Two finished");
        }
    }
}
```

AController:

```
@Controller
class AController {
    final BService bService;

    @Autowired
    AController(BService bService) {
        this.bService = bService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/underTest")
    String methodUnderTest() {
        return bService.getDummyString();
    }
}
```

BService:

```
@Service
class BService {
    String getDummyString() {
        return "ABC";
    }
}
```

The exception I receive:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
mypackage.controller.BService#0 bean.getDummyString();
Wanted 1 time:
-> at mypackage.controller.AControllerMvcTest$NestedTests1.testOne(AControllerMvcTest.java:45)
But was 2 times:
-> at mypackage.controller.AController.methodUnderTest(AController.java:19)
-> at mypackage.controller.AController.methodUnderTest(AController.java:19)
```

The same test passes if there are no nested tests.

In both cases (nested tests and no nested tests)

- the tests are executed sequentially (println to the console)
- bService is the same instance in both tests (checked with debugger)

**My Questions**

- why adding @Nested caused my test to fail
- how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an open bug in Spring Boot: [@MockBean fields are not reset for JUnit 5 @Nested tests #12470](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12470).

It is blocked by another issue in Spring Framework: [Discover test configuration on enclosing class for nested test class [SPR-15366] #19930](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19930)

The latter is scheduled for 5.3 M2, so hopefully this won't be an issue soon.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring testing support does not work with nested tests unless you repeat all spring-related annotations in all nested test classes. I recommend to forgo nesting in this case.

Comment: I’m not sure they have documented something not working, i.e. a missing feature, but I did a deep dive into the spring code when implementing https://github.com/jlink/jqwik-spring. You either duplicate (most of) the annotations in nested classes or it won’t work. The shortcomings sections in https://github.com/jlink/jqwik-spring holds for both the Jupiter and jqwik integration.